# Workflow form generated by SharePoint designer 2007 not seen by users

Tags: forms, sharepoint, workflow, designer

I’ve designed a form for a user here to collect data for a workflow. I used SharePoint designer to build a custom approval form.  When the workflow is initiated I am receive and email to ‘Edit Task’.   I click on the Edit Task button and it takes to the form.  I enter the information requested and my tasks lists and calendar are updated.  However when I set the email to go to the user who will be entering the data( approval) the ‘Edit Task’ Button takes him to an error page “404 page not found”.

It seems that when I created the form SharePoint saved it to a local server and not to the Sharepoint server.  I notice that the out of the box workflows go to this directory: http://vaww.visn16.portal.va.gov/sites/HOU/IMS/VistA/Help/_layouts/...

However my form is in the Workflow directory: http://vaww.visn16.portal.va.gov/sites/HOU/IMS/VistA/Help/Workflows/

I use my Explorer to go to My Network Places and I can see the directory for my workflow  and workflow form. However other users with my same permission can get to the Workflow directory but only they cannot see the form.  The other files associated with the workflow are present for them. Why can’t others access(see) the form?  Users that I have asked to test this workflow all have full permissions like me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the page that you navigate to when you click the Edit Task button is not checked out to you.  If it is checked out, check it in and others should be able to see the page.